# Is the TzStats API discontinued?

Tags: api

Has the TzStats API been shut down?

It appears `api.tzstats.com` has become an unknown host.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the makers of TzStats built a new platform TzPro, and have now deprecated TzStats. They've made multiple announcements about this over the course of a few months on Twitter, Reddit, Discord, etc: https://x.com/tzstats?s=20

In the world of decentralised apps, its essential to follow social channels for your baker, node providers, service providers, etc, to keep on top of updates and changes